# Finding $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 2} (x^3 - x) = 6$ using epsilon-delta.

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

> Find $$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 2} (x^3 - x) = 6$$ using epsilon-delta.

I have attempted the following:

Given $ε>0$, the exists a particular chosen $δ$.

Then whenever $0<|x-2|<δ$, 
$|x^3 - x - 6| = |x(x^2 - 1) - 6| = |x(x-1)(x+1) - 6|$

I do not know how to continue from here.

Is it possible to do the following?

$|x ((x-2)+1) ((x-2)+3) - 6| ≤ |x (|x-2|+1) (|x-2|+1) - 6|$?

Thanks and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Factor out an $x$ in the expression, and you will get a difference of two squares. Can you factor that expression further?

Comment: I think you mean $x \to 2$?

Comment: you don't need epsilon-delta per se. You can just factor the expression and you will be able to let $x$ go to $2$.

Comment: I need to prove using epsilon-delta definition.

Comment: @TobyMak you mean $x(x-1)(x+1)-6 $?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. By the way, why do you want to find the limit using epsilon-delta? The limit obviously exists, so you can just directly calculate the expression *without the limit*.

Comment: @TobyMak My immediate guess is that he is told to use $\epsilon$-$\delta$ because his textbook / teacher thinks it's important to practice the technique on problems that are so simple that you can clearly see what the solution should be.

Comment: -1 You should include your own effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $|x^3-x-6|=|x-2||x^2+2x+3|$. For $x$ near $2$ we have $1 \le x \le 3$, hence

$|x^3-x-6| \le |x-2|(9+6+3)=18|x-2|$.

Your turn !